# Extract elements from JSONObject in Android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a JSONObject called object.

It has alot of objects of the class Books.

This is the print of the first element :

```
I/System.out: {"id":"1","author":"Paula Hawkins","description":"EVERY DAY THE SAME\n\nRachel   Soon she is deeply entangled not only in the investigation but in the lives of everyone involved. Has she done more harm than good?","publication_date":"13\/01\/2015","title":"The girl on the train","url_image":"hawkins.jpg"}
```

I would like to get the id, the author and such, but I don't know how to access it.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JSONArray mainObject = new JSONArray(total.toString());
for (int i = 0; i < mainObject.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = mainObject.getJSONObject(i);
    int id = object.getInt("id");  //This will have the value of the id
    String author = object.getString("author");
    String description = object.getString("description");
    String publication_date = object.getString("publication_date");
    String title = object.getString("title");
    String url_image = object.getString("url_image");

}
System.out.println(mainObject.get(1));

for(int i =0; i<mainObject.length(); i++){
    book = new Book();
}
```

This is the code on how I am creating the object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out!.

```
System.out.println(mainObject.getJSONObject(1).get("id"));
```

You get the object 1 in this case and .get the name of the attribute you want to get.

Thanks anyways and I hope this answers helps other people!